# C++ testing suite that survives asserts in code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, visual-c++, automated-tests

I am trying to set up testing for my project, I have exceptions disabled and have defined my asserts to call std::abort. Both gtest and Catch are only able to fail on one test that calls std::abort as it kills the whole testing suite.
My projects compile into DLLs which the testing project/executable references. Aside from:

1. enabling exceptions and having my asserts throw
2. creating a custom compile target and doing something similar as to 1.
3. restructuring code to not rely on assert to fail

do I have any other options? I would prefer not to enable exceptions because of design/speed concerns.

Comment: googletest supports this. Lookup for death tests.

Comment: Death test test that the application aborts. The way I am structuring the code it will abort anytime there is an unrecoverable error, which can occur virtually anytime.

Comment: That's probably a not so good design.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two questions here:

```
1. Can I do testing without exceptions?
```

Yes, you can. If `std::abort` doesn't give you enough information you can try returning error codes using `std::quick_exit`

```
2. Can I keep the test suite going after a failure?
```

This really has nothing to do with the former. Keeping a test suite going after some error is technical challenge as the program can fail a test for terrible unrecoverable reasons like dividing by zero or the stack might have been smashed.

The only way to keep running the test suite is if the tests are run in separate processes.

In one of my projects I have switch flag pared in `main` that causes the program to be run in test mode, which then directs to a specific test. A bash script then iterates over the ~100 such tests.